# Cloudwatch custom metric math

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I have a custom metric in Cloudwatch that has the value of 1 or 0. I need to create a pie widget in a dashboard that will represent the percentage of how many 1 and 0 i have in a time period selected. Is this possible only with metric math? If so, how? If not, how else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only publishing 0s and 1s, then the average statistic will give you the percentage of 1s. You simply add your metric to the graph and set Statistic to Average, and put the id to `m1`

For pie chart you need two metrics, percentage of 1s and percentage of 0s. Since these are the only 2 values, percentage of zeros will be `1 - percentage of 1s`. You can get this by adding a metric math expression `1 - m1`.

Pie chart will by default only display the value of the last datapoint. You need to change this by clicking to the **Options** tab on the edit graph view, **Widget type** should be ***Pie***, and selecting ***Time range value shows the value from the entire time range.***

Example source of the graph would be:

```
{
    "metrics": [
        [ { "expression": "1-m1", "label": "zeros", "id": "e1", "region": "eu-west-1" } ],
        [ YOUR METRIC DEFINITION, { "id": "m1", "label": "ones" } ]
    ],
    "period": 60,
    "view": "pie",
    "stacked": false,
    "stat": "Average",
    "setPeriodToTimeRange": true,
    "sparkline": false,
    "region": "YOUR REGION"
}
```